# CodeIgniter HTTP 500 error when loading model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am hosting a CodeIgniter site locally using MAMP on my mac.

Whenever I try to load a model the site runs an HTTP 500 error and I'm not sure what is going one. I suspect I've overlooked something very minor but I'm just not seeing it.

Controller: main.php

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class Main extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
    //load content model
    $this->load->model('content_model');

    //grab content from the database
    //$data['content'] = $this->content_model->get_content(0);

    //display content
    $this->load->view('main_view');
}
 }
 ?>
```

Model: content_model.php

```
 <?php 
 class Content_model extends CI_Model {

function __construct()
{
    //Call the Model constructor
    parent::__construct();
}

public function get_content($navID)
{
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $this->db->where('navID', $navID);
    $query = $this->db->get('pmlSiteContent');
    return $query->result();
}
 ?>
```

autoload.php

```
 <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
 $autoload['packages'] = array();
 $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
 $autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form', 'file');
 $autoload['config'] = array();
 $autoload['language'] = array();
 $autoload['model'] = array();
 ?>
```

database.php

```
 <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 $active_group = 'default';
 $active_record = TRUE;

 $db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost:8889';
 $db['default']['username'] = 'root';
 $db['default']['password'] = 'root';
 $db['default']['database'] = 'pmlcms';
 $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
 $db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
 $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
 $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
 $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
 $db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
 $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
 $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
 $db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
 $db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
 $db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
 ?>
```

What am I missing? Help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: what does your apache `error.log` file say

Comment: Did you check the error log? Try to set `$config['log_threshold']` in you config.php

Comment: Christian has it solved but I will set my $config['log_threshold'] since my error.log displayed no error message. Thanks for pointing that out, I'm sure it will come in handy later!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in `content_model.php`
you missed the end bracket of the class. It's a bad idea to use the end `php` tags

Comment: That was it! Thank you much, totally missed that!